# Calculus 1: Optimization Word Problem Messy Algebra

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization, word-problem

I cannot seem to get the right answer here. The algebra gets very messy.

You are going down a beach that runs north-south. You want to go to a lighthouse 4 miles off the beach at a bearing of 150 degrees. Your car can travel on land and sea. It can go 60mph on the beach and 8mph on water. How far down the beach should you go to minimize the time it takes to get to the lighthouse?

Here is the work I've done. I've attempted it multiple times, but I lose my way in the algebra.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMHnI.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68i19.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps you can parameterise the problem by the angle from the beach one takes to reach the lighthouse after driving down the beach? You should end up with some formula like $\cos \theta = {8 \over 60}$. I ended up with something like $2 (\sqrt{3}-{2 \over \sqrt{221}}) \approx3.20$.

Comment: @copper.hat : Your answer is correct, but I don't quite understand how one can use cosine as a relation of two rates. I'm also not sure how to fit that in into my previous equation for total time and its derivative. Or were you suggesting I use a completely different equation?

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting a different parameterisation of the problem. Go down the beach for some distance and then head towards the lighthouse at any angle $\theta$ to the beach. (This angle fixes the distance on the beach.) Figure out the total time in terms of $\theta$ and optimise over this. The resulting equations are a bit easier to resolve using trigonometric identities.

Comment: @copper.hat: Could you say more about how to figure out the total time in terms of the angle? I'm having trouble setting up an equation.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$T = {l \over 60}+ {w \over 8}$,
$w = {4 \sin {\pi \over 6} \over \sin \theta}$,
$l = 4 \cos {\pi \over 6} - w \cos \theta$.

$T(\theta) = \frac{2\sqrt{3}\sin \theta −2\cos \theta +15}{60 \sin \theta }$

$T('\theta) = {2 -15 \cos \theta \over 60 \sin^2 \theta}$